# Unity: Help needed with rendering voxels and performance

Tags: unity-game-engine, rendering, voxel

So here is the deal, i have an enemy that is rigged and consists out of quite a few voxels. [image]

When i run the game i get very bad performance overall when its rendering the model because of the amount of objects it needs to render. How can i improve that?

Here's the things i have thought about:
Only rendering the faces we actually can see,
Or maybe using some sort of GPU Instancing?

Anyways, i would like to know how i could resolve such a problem. Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing how you've actually implemented your voxels in game (i.e what components each voxel consists of and how you're currently managing them) it's hard to offer much specific advice.

In general though there are a few things to consider:

- Faces that aren't oriented towards the camera won't be
  rendered by default.  What you might want to investigate is
  [Occlusion
  Culling](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/OcclusionCulling.html), but
  since your character is not static within the scene you might not get
  much performance improvement from that.  The code to
  constantly check whether objects are occluded might end up costing
  more CPU than not implementing it.
- Rendering might not be your actual bottleneck for performance.  If each of your voxels is doing some work every update (such as collision detection), then that's going to hit your performance much harder than rendering the objects, particularly for cubic voxels.  You'll need to use the [Profiler](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Profiler.html) to figure that out.
- You need to consider whether you actually REALLY need all those voxels to be in the scene all the time or whether you can replace them with a single GameObject until you need to interact with them, then bring them into the scene as needed.  For example, you might replace the upper arm with a mesh that mirrors the shape of the total voxels for that body part.  Then when that part is shot, for example, you can detect the point of collision and instantiate the necessary voxels around that point to react as desired, then rebuild the arm mesh to reflect the changed shape.

It might also be worth looking into Unity's [Data-oriented Technology Stack (DOTS)](https://unity.com/dots) features, although that could be overkill for this situation.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for your detailed answer. I will look into Unity's profiler and see what's the actual bottleneck, but I'm pretty sure that's the rendering of all the verts and triangles. The voxels also don't use colliders, so it can't be the physics. I will also look into DOTS, thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0):

A little late here, but in my case I just had to remove the unused vertices that I had in the mesh (keeping in mind that in my case, I already had implemented the rendering of only the faces that can be seen).

I was working on a project where I was making a voxel based terrain, pretty similar to Minecraft.

When inspecting the chunk meshes that I was generating through code, I realized that I had meshes with `780K` vertices, when I really only used `20K` or so. By removing unused vertices and assigning a smaller array to the mesh instead of the original array (with `780K` vertices), I was able to get a huge performance boost - from `50ms` long frames to `0.1ms`.

This was happening because I was allocating an array that would be big enough to fit all possible vertices and triangles inside it, but only `20K` vertices would be used and the other `760K` in my case would just be left empty but still assigned to the mesh.

By assigning an array with no pointless vertices that weren't being used, I also reduced my RAM usage from around `10GB` to "only" `120MB`.

I hope this helps, because this confused me for a few hours until I finally realized what was going on.